# Docker Postgres + pgAdmin error: "closed the connection unexpectedly" when Viewing Data

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I have issues to view my database's data in pgadmin.

I set up two docker container, one with postgres and one with pgadmin like so:

Postgres:

```
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker-volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

pgAdmin:

```
docker run --name pgadmin -p 5050:80  -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret" -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

I can connect to my postgres container and can see my database and its tables.

But when I try to view the data in one table, right click the table and "View/Edit Data" pgadmin shows "server closed the connection unexpectedly....".

Using my javscript API I can work with the database without problems. So the issue seems to be pgadmin specific, I guess.

Thanks folks.